# Как получить лицензию на приложение

Tags: python, windows, лицензирование

пишу свои программы на Python, хочу что-бы при запуске программы не вылезало окно что мое приложение может навредить компьютеру. Уже пробовал устанавливать приложение через установщик, но это тоже не помогает. Как сделать что-бы windows доверяла моему приложению?

Comment: Это не лицензия, Вам нужен сертификат для подписи файла. Ищите по словам "WINDOWS CODE SIGNING CERTIFICATE
". стоит 60-100 долл в год. В странах, на которые наложены санкции, могут быть проблемы с покупкой.

Comment: А нет способа сделать это бесплатно?

Comment: нет. иначе кол-во вирусов было бы просто бесконечное.